# Escape jQuery node into text so that HTML code is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to output HTML to the screen (not render it). For example, given the following:

```
<div></div>
<button>escape</button>
<pre><code></code></pre>
```

And using jQuery to create some HTML on the fly:

```
$('div').html('<p>lorem</p>');

$('button').on('click',function () {
    $('code').text($('div'));
});
```

Is there a way to display:

```
<div><p>lorem</p></div>
```

Instead of what I'm seeing:

```
[object Object]
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qxxwbtb4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `outerHTML` property:

```
$('button').on('click',function () {
    $('code').text($('div').prop('outerHTML'));
});
```

Note that this will only return the `outerHTML` (or any other selected property/attribute) of the *first* `div` returned by the selector.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).
- jQuery:

  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: I don't suppose there is an easy way to enforce indentation within the `<code>` blocks?

Comment: There is, although it depends on the original indentation: `code { white-space: pre; }` or `pre-wrap`.

Comment: Hmm so if one is creating nodes on the fly you're out of luck? [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qxxwbtb4/4/)